# call controller from drop down onchange in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp, controller

I m beginner to cakephp and trying to call controller and its function on onchange in drop down item.
I have a dropdown and want to pass a parameter dataid to function getData(). my code is missing something as below

```
echo $this->Form->input('Preferred City', array('empty'=>'Select Preferred City','options' => $cits, 'onchange' => '');
```

need to call getData() in DataController

```
class DataController extends AppController {
public function getData($dataid = null) { 
//codes
}
}
```

please correct my code wherever it is needed.

Comment: Read the book? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html Also there is no code to correct... At least I'm not going to do your work and write that for you. So show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly call a controller function from that, you can only call a javscript function.  You will need to make a javascript function that makes an AJAX request to the controller function you need to call.